# Injectables not working in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

I recently started playing with `Angular2`. I've been trying to get injectables to work for about half a day now, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

To keep it as simple as possible, I copied code from [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) in the official webpage. Demo itself works fine, but when i try to use injectables, I get an error saying

> ORIGINAL ERROR: Cannot resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent. Make
>   sure they all have valid type or annotations.

### My typescript file

```typescript
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap,} from 'angular2/angular2';

class Names {}

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    injectables: [Names]
})
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
    name: string;
    constructor(names: Names) {
        this.name = 'Alice';
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

P.S. As in the [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html), I'm using `Traceur`, `SystemJS` and `Angular2 alpha (23)`

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't seem to get this error. It works just fine in 23. Do you have a plunker replica

Comment: @PSL here's the link for plunker (instead of adding a typescript file, I've added whatever I've got from 1.5 compiler). If you remove 'names' parameter from constructor, it starts working, though, it doesn't do the injection: http://plnkr.co/edit/OYItENWlIAd4L4GG9ZRc?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your compiler does not add parameters properties to the `MyAppComponent` (from looking at your [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OYItENWlIAd4L4GG9ZRc?p=preview)). I think this is the problem. If you add

```js
MyAppComponent.parameters = [[Names]]
```

then all will works well.

1. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0XYEYGclsTdVjLuD3cG?p=preview) is your plunker with fix.
2. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCzvFPZH5Q1szJP9vrmT?p=preview) is the same example in TS (with ES6)

**UPD** Thanks to @GrayFox for pointing out the correct way (see the comment bellow):

> For future references - use `--emitDecoratorMetadata` flag when using tsc or add `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` to the configuration if you're using gulp-typescript

See TypeScript compiler options [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) (you can find `emitDecoratorMetada` there).

Comment: Thanks for catching this! I'll try to investigate why my compiler doesn't add parameters

Comment: @Alvydas, for me it worked when I changed my typescript compiler to target 1.6. I am not seeing any difference in the output though, shouldn't I see any difference?

Comment: For future references - use `--emitDecoratorMetadata` flag when using `tsc` or add `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` to the configuration if you're using `gulp-typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " >
   <DebugSymbols>true < /DebugSymbols>
   < TypeScriptRemoveComments > false < /TypeScriptRemoveComments>
   < TypeScriptSourceMap > true < /TypeScriptSourceMap>
   < TypeScriptAdditionalFlags > $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)--emitDecoratorMetadata < /TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>
 < /PropertyGroup>
 < PropertyGroup Condition= " '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " >
   <DebugSymbols>true < /DebugSymbols>
   < TypeScriptRemoveComments > true < /TypeScriptRemoveComments>
   < TypeScriptSourceMap > false < /TypeScriptSourceMap>
   < TypeScriptAdditionalFlags > $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)--emitDecoratorMetadata < /TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>
 < /PropertyGroup>
```

into your *.njsproj file at the end.