# Injectables in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am playing around with Angular2. As a basis, I used the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) project from the [angular.io](http://www.angular.io) page.

Everything seems to work fine, but as soon as I try to inject a service (`ItemService`) into my `AppComponent` I get following exception:

> Error during instantiation of Token(ComponentRef)!. ORIGINAL ERROR: Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent. Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

I have seen similar issues on the internet (including stackoverflow, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239758/injectables-not-working-in-angular-2-0)), but none of them seem to solve my problem. Does any body have any idea, what the problem could be?

I have also seen some solutions (for example the ones in the Angular2 repo) which decorate the injectable class with the `Injectable`-annotation. However this doesn't work for me, as it is not defined in `angular.d.ts`. Am I using a wrong version?

You can find my solution in following Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7kK1BtcuEHjaspwLTmsg

For the record, you can also find my two files below. Please note that the `app.js` from the Plunker is the JavaScript file generated out of my TypeScript file below, the exception is always the same.

`index.html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Angular2</title>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.23/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app></app>
        <script>
            System.import('js/app');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`js/app.ts`:

```typescript
/// <reference path="../../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap, For, If} from "angular2/angular2";

class Item {
    id:number;
    name:string;

    constructor(id:number, name:string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class ItemService {
    getItems() {
        return [
            new Item(1, "Bill"),
            new Item(2, "Bob"),
            new Item(3, "Fred")
        ];
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    injectables: [ItemService]
})
@View({
    template: `<h1>Testing Angular2</h1>
               <ul>
                 <li *for="#item of items">
                   {{item.id}}: {{item.name}} |
                   <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="toggleSelected(item);">
                     {{selectedItem == item ? "unselect" : "select"}}
                   </a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
               <item-details *if="selectedItem" [item]="selectedItem"></item-details>`,
    directives: [For, If, DetailComponent]
})
class AppComponent {
    items:Item[];
    selectedItem:Item;

    constructor(itemService:ItemService) {
        this.items = itemService.getItems();
    }

    toggleSelected(item) {
        this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem == item ? null : item;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'item-details',
    properties: {
        item: "item"
    }
})
@View({
    template: `<span>You selected {{item.name}}</span>`
})
class DetailComponent {
    item:Item;
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check for couple of things:-

1) Make sure you are using the correct version of typescript (1.5.x) installed from your package location. () If you have previous versions of typescript installed then merely using "tsc" command could be pointing to the existing (< 1.5) location from the environment path.

2) Make sure you use `--emitDecoratorMetadata` flag with the tsc command. It is necessary so the javascript output creates the metadata for the decorators.

3) `Error - Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined` 
 Because `AppComponent` directive has a dependency on `DetailComponent` which has not been defined yet (by the time the synchronous `__decorate(` function runs to resolve the dependencies) and the way TS compiles the hoisted variable `DetailComponent` is undefined then (The IIFE for that below is yet to run). Try moving the declaration of `DetailComponent` before `AppComponent`. Or just move it to a different file and import it.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'item-details',
    properties: {
        item: "item"
    }
})
@View({
    template: `<span>You selected {{item.name}}</span>`
})
class DetailComponent {
    item:Item;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    injectables: [ItemService]
})
@View({
    template: `<h1>Testing Angular2</h1>
               <ul>
                 <li *for="#item of items">
                   {{item.id}}: {{item.name}} |
                   <a href="#" (click)="toggleSelected(item);">
                     {{selectedItem == item ? "unselect" : "select"}}
                   </a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
               <item-details *if="selectedItem" [item]="selectedItem"></item-details>`,
    directives: [For, If, DetailComponent]
})

class AppComponent {
    items:Item[];
    selectedItem:Item;

    constructor(itemService:ItemService) {
        this.items = itemService.getItems();
    }

    toggleSelected(item) {
        this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem == item ? null : item;
        return false;
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**Edit**

**As of angular a26 if you face issues with respect to following the current documentation (as of now) [follow this link if it helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770222/module-angular2-angular2-has-no-exported-member-for/30770446#30770446) as there are some relevant changes.**

Comment: Also noticed you have `../../` on typings that is valid if typings is outside rootfolder, but if it is inside your root you may want to remove one `../`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Moving the definition of `DetailComponent` before `AppComponent` didn't change anything. And it works if I don't use `ItemService` but define the `Item`s inline, for example in the constructor of `AppComponent`. It is really related to the `injectables`. The typings are outside of the root folder, so I guess that shouldn't be a problem either..

Comment: @PzYon infact it just worked fine for me when i moved it. Are you sure if your file is compiled properly? I am using v23.a as well. I cannot access plunker at this point so cant really see what is going on...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm afraid, I'm not an expert in TypeScript, but as far as I know, it (re)compiles correctly and the order doesn't matter in my case. I am using TypeScript 1.5 beta on Windows executed from within WebStorm. I pass following options to the TypeScript compiler: `--module "commonjs" --target es5`. If I additionally pass `--emitDecoratorMetadata` (as specified in the angular.io quickstart), I get `Error: Cannot start compiler process`. Maybe this is the cause.. If I compare my compiled .js file with your's, I can see that I am missing the `__metadata`-lines.

Comment: @PzYon That is part of the problem. Infact i never got the error you mentioned in the question, that seems to be with the compiler. However once yu got that resolved you might end up getting `Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined` because you try to inject the service that is defined later, typescript only transpiles to javascript which meant it converts your DetailComponent Class defined later in the file to the function assigning it to variable with invocation of IIFE

Comment: with `var DetailsComponent = ` which mean that when the previous annotation (which depends on) executes this will not be defined yet. See it working here http://plnkr.co/edit/OFn65j?p=preview Otherwise i guess your issue is same as what [this guy got](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239758/injectables-not-working-in-angular-2-0) I always have my metadata turned on, which i guess is needed with es5 mode on.. ex:- `tsc --watch -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata js/app.ts`

Comment: I can confirm that it's related to the `--emitDecoratorMetadata` and that it's required. But the initial problem was that even though TypeScript 1.5 was installed, I was running TypeScript 1.3, as it was still somewhere in the path variables.. Thanks for bringing me on the right track with the compiler!

Comment: @PzYon I had that issue. I was initially using 1.4 installed due to the env path and then started pointing explicitly to the package installed location. Also these versions does not support --emitDecoratorMetadata so that gave me a clue. But Did you not get into the ordering issue that i mentioned originally as well.

Comment: Moving the dependency above the appcomponent fixed this problem for me (and probably ensuring that `atom-typescript` was setting the `emitDecoratorMetadata` flag by setting it in the `tsconfig.json` that it generates on first use).

Comment: is injectables is still there in the latest build because i am trying to make the demo app posted in angular.io but doesn't seems to work as well i looked into angular2.d.ts injectables is not present in defination file also

Comment: @PranayDutta `injectables` is now `appInjector` with latest alpha.

Comment: FWIW, I was stuck on the **appInjector** step of the Getting Started exercise as well.  When I added the --emitDecoratorMetadata flag, the error went away.  I think it would be very helpful to get that requirement into the official docs.

Comment: This answer is no longer current and could use a review.

Answer (score 3):

My setup: I am running WebStorm 10.0.2 on Windows, using TypeScript 1.5 beta (compiled to ES5) and node/npm.

Thanks to PSL's help, I found several problems with my setup. <del>They were not related to the code, e.g. not to the order of the class definitions, etc.</del> Just for the record I would like to summarize the issues I had.. Most of them have been mentioned by PSL, but maybe other people have the same problems, e.g. related to the compiler in WebStorm.

Here are the problems I had:

- Even though I configured WebStorm to use TypeScript 1.5 installed via npm, an old version (1.3) was used, as this was also installed on my system (I think together with Visual Studio) and registered in the `%path%` variable
- I configured WebStorm to use a "Custom Compiler Version" for TypeScript (in settings/Languages and Frameworks/TypeScript), with following arguments: `-emitDecoratorMetadata -m commonjs -t es5 -sourceMap`. This some how doesn't work.. I'm not sure, if it is related to an issue in WebStorm. Without the `-emitDecoratorMetadata` flag it compiled, but the `injectables` didn't work.

  [Update, 9. June 2015: Yes, it is related to an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16678) in WebStorm]
- However I need the `-emitDecoratorMetadata`-flag in order for the `injectables` in Angular2 to work.
- My solution was to add a custom "File Watcher" in WebStorm (instead of using the "builtin Compiler"-function) with following arguments: `-emitDecoratorMetadata -m commonjs -t es5 --sourceMap $FilePath$`

Lessons learned when working with Angular2, TypeScript 1.5 and WebStorm:

- Ensure TypeScript 1.5 is really the version which is used to compile the ts files (e.g. in your IDE).
- Ensure the `-emitDecoratorMetadata` is specified.
- <del>It doesn't make a difference, if the classes are defined in a specific order or in own files, etc.</del> -> Order does matter! Splitting the classes/components into different files solves the problem and generally leads to better maintanable files.

Thanks again to PSL for his valuable input!

Comment: Nice answer. But i cannot understand that in your original question the way you are injecting DetailsComponent before it is defined.. it should give the error `Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined` which makes much sense. because the line `directives: [angular2_1.For, angular2_1.If, DetailComponent]` runs before `var DetailComponent = (function () {` which means that hoisted variable `DetailComponent ` which contains the definision will be undefined then and also `__decorate` is not asyncronous as well. Defining on its own file and importing it of course will be just fine.

Comment: Yep, of course you're right: Order does matter, I get the same exception you do, if I have my injectable component (`DetailComponent`) after the component into which I would like to inject it (`AppComponent`). I updated my answer accordingly. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for confirming... I could not really comprehend the fact that why you wouldn't.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem. Below were the resolution:

1. --emitDecoratorMetadata was missed in tsc
2. If I was injecting service from same file it was failing, but when I put the service is some other file and when imported that, it started working. probably bug in Angular2 version I was using.