# Webstorm with TypeScript v1.5 Beta: "Cannot start compiler process" when using the "--emitDecoratorMetadata" option

Tags: typescript, webstorm, angular

Webstorm: v10.0.3
TypeScript: v1.5.0.Beta
Nodejs: v0.12.3

The issue is the Compiler Option: "**--emitDecoratorMetadata**"
(which you need for Angularjs2 & TypeScript)

Two ways to transcompile:
**1) GUI: Webstorm|Settings|Languages & Frameworks|TypeScript: "Command line options". Using the "--emitDecoratorMetadata" compiler option results in the compiler NOT starting.**
2) CMD Line: compiling with tsc.exe from the command line using this compiler option does work, the compiler starts and runs without errors.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311514/injectables-in-angular2) for more information.

I'm looking forward to v10.0.4 in that case.. ;)

In the meanwhile you could use a file watcher as a workaround. That's more or less the same as calling the compiler from the command line (your second option), just that it will be executed automatically as soon as the files change:

- Settings / Tools / FileWatchers
- Add a new one, name it `TypeScript 1.5 Compilation` or something
  like that
- Use following settings:

  - Select `Immediate file synchronization`
  - Program: `C:\Users\Peter.Sample\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd` (or where ever your TS 1.5 compiler is located)
  - Arguments: `-emitDecoratorMetadata -m commonjs -t es5 --sourceMap $FilePath$`

That should do the job for the moment. You might however be missing the compiler messages/warnings within the dev. environment while coding.

Answer (score 1):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16678

The issue is fixed in **v10.0.4** and v11 EAP-- wait till it will be released.