# Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'For'

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.5

I am following the tutorial on the official Angular2 website.

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html

Here is my .ts file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, For} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'display'
})
@View({
    template: '<p>name: {{myName}}</p>' +
                '<p>Friends:</p>' +
                '<ul>'+
                 '<li *for="#name of names">'+
                    '{{name}}'+
                 '<li>'+
                '<ul>',
    directives: [For]
})
class DisplayComponent{
    myName: string;
    names: Array<string>;

    constructotr(){
        this.myName = "Alice";
        this.names = ["Winston", "Alex", "Shannon", "Irizu"];
    }
}

bootstrap(DisplayComponent);
```

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.23/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <display></display>
    <script>
      System.import('show-properties');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And I have installed angular2, Rx and es6-promise.

Still the error persists.

> message TS6042: Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
>   message TS6032: File change detected. Starting incremental
>   compilation... show-properties.ts(2,37): error TS2305: Module
>   '"angular2/angular2"' has no expo rted member 'For'. message TS6042:
>   Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

---

**Update**

Here is my updated .ts code:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {
 ComponentAnnotation as Component,
  ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap, NgFor
} from 'angular2/angular2';



@Component({
    selector: 'display'
})
@View({
    template: '<p>name: {{myName}}</p>' +
                '<p>Friends:</p>' +
                '<ul>'+
                 '<li *ng-for="#name of names">'+
                    '{{name}}'+
                 '<li>'+
                '<ul>',
    directives: [NgFor]
})
class DisplayComponent{
    myName: string;
    names: Array<string>;

    constructotr(){
        this.myName = "Alice";
        this.names = ["Winston", "Alex", "Shannon", "Irizu"];
    }
}

bootstrap(DisplayComponent);
```

angular2.d.ts is still alpha 26.

Now there is no error message and I can see

name:
Friends:

But no values are inserted.
And I've got an error message:

> show-properties.ts(7,2): error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof
>   ComponentAnnotation ' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
>   show-properties.ts(10,2): error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof
>   ViewAnnotation' is  not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
>   message TS6042: Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your  issue is that the documentation is not in sync. If you followed the documentation for installation recently then it would have installed the typings for latest version alpha26, which has a lot of broken changes. And the documentation uses a23 version with that version of code. You can either

1) Update your typings to older version that matches v23, which you can [find it here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/396000ead5cd89888c814f669cbb0ef1f7e38f92/angular2/angular2.d.ts). Copy the contents and replace it in `./typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts`.

2) Upgrade your angular script to [alpha 26](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular2.dev.js) and fix couple of things.

- `For` is now `NgFor`, `If` is now `NgIf`
- `*for` is now `*ng-for`, `*if` is now `*ng-if` ...
- `injectables` (if you intend to use in your directive settings) is now `appInjector`
- install typings for `es6-promise`, `rx` and `rx-lite` using the same `tsd query xxx --action install` command.

  **[Demo - 23](http://plnkr.co/edit/VpMH5T?p=preview)**

  **[Demo - 26](http://plnkr.co/edit/j9CV1T?p=preview)**

You could also use the startup from [angular-class webpack starter](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter).

Comment: Hi I followed the 2nd suggestion. Now I get an error message.Please see my update. thank you

Comment: When using Typescipt you should not have to use that `annotation as` i guess. I just do `import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';` The one was for es6 code in plnkr. Also install the typings as i mentioned above in the updated answer, if it asks for it. Also note the spelling of `constructor` there is a typo in your code. Hope you should be able to figure out here on.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. The problem has finally been solved :)

Comment: I'm working with alpha 31 an I'm getting - has no exported member 'view'

Comment: @JasonSpick use import {  Component,View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2'; instead - i think they changed the names...

Comment: @PSL They were renamed again. Now it's *ngFor, and *ngIf. Also, they're implicitly included so there's no need to define them as View directives

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the renamed for to ng-for. Same with ng-if.
Just update it in your ts file and view.

I have a few samples here if you are interested in some working Angular 2.0 examples: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-examples

Comment: Thanks TGH, I have made my program working. After followed a few of tutorials of Angular2, I found that there are too many out-of-date documents, break updates etc. I decided to wait until the stable version arrived. But appreciate your help :)