# No exported member 'view'

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I'm following the Angular2 5 minute example and typescript is throwing an error on:

```
import {Component,View,bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

gives error:

```
Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'view'.
```

I see there is a related question on [exported member for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770222/module-angular2-angular2-has-no-exported-member-for) but it's for alpha 23/26 where we are currently on 31.

Has anyone ran into this or have a resolution?

Comment: Interesting now that this works. The only thing I did was update git on my pc. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interesting now that this works. The only thing I did was update git on my pc.

Restarting the IDEs is required if you download new files (like the angular definitions) in the background.

FWIW atom-typescript provides a sync option for this reason : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#sync