# Cannot get simple service injected into component

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I can't for the life of me get a simple service to inject into an Angular2 component. Everything is transpiling but i just keep getting:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSurveyItem' of undefined
```

And when i check in the constructor of my component, the service is undefined so i am really stuck after spending the whole day on this.  There are some similar questions on here, but i was already doing what those suggested so i am sure i am missing something else. I am pretty new to this, but it seems what i am doing is pretty basic.

**My ServiceItem "Model"**

```
export class SurveyItem {
    constructor(public id: number, public imageUrl: string) {}
}
```

**My Service (ServiceItemService)**

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

import { SurveyItem } from '../models/survey-item.model';

@Injectable()
export class SurveyItemService{

    getSurveyItem(): SurveyItem {
    return { id: 23, imageUrl: '/secure/files/189008d0-5a8e-4e69-927c-0fdfa6f7ea7a.jpg'}
   } 
}
```

**My Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

import {SurveyItem} from './model/survey-item.model';
import {SurveyItemService} from './services/survey-item.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'survey-item',
    template: '<div><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1></div>',
    providers: [SurveyItemService]
})

export class SurveyItemComponent implements OnInit { 

   pageTitle: string = 'Survey Item';
   surveyItem: SurveyItem;

    constructor(private surveyItemService: SurveyItemService) {
       console.log(surveyItemService);
    }

    getSurveyItem(id: any): void {
        this.surveyItem = this.surveyItemService.getSurveyItem();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getSurveyItem(23);
    }
}
```

**Bootstrap**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {SurveyItemComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(SurveyItemComponent);
```

I am sure someone is going to tell me this is something very obvious, but i really can't see what i have missed.

Comment: u are injecting so u dont need this `providers: [SurveyItemService]
` Please check on console for error.

Comment: i have had the code with or without that line (i didn't have it, but saw it on the angular docs so put it in). Either way, my service is still undefined and not getting injected.

Comment: If the service wasn't injected, there should be injection errors too. It may be a problem with emitDecoratorMetadata, have you tried to inject it explicitly with @Inject ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311514/injectables-in-angular2

Comment: If i remove the call to the service " this.surveyItem = this.surveyItemService.getSurveyItem();" then there are no errors, so there are no service injection errors, just an undefined service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested it with **RC7** version and its working without any error. As you are using older version try to follow below suggestions,

**Bootstrap**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {SurveyItemComponent} from './app.component';
import {SurveyItemService} from './services/survey-item.service';

bootstrap(SurveyItemComponent,[SurveyItemService]);
```

**My Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'survey-item',
    template: '<div><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1></div>',
    // providers: [SurveyItemService] <----commenting it
})
```

---

In case you need a reference, below link is in latest version and its working. Posting working link here. It may or may not help you.

Check browser's console.

**https://plnkr.co/edit/FDY4CBAPcaxxlH32ADQp?p=preview**

Comment: Yes i was using an old version but upgrading didn't fix it, as it seems i was using an old version and visual 2013 doesn't seem to be so great with TypeScript (i am sure its a setting but can't find it). I upgraded and shifted project to visual studio code and it now works, i just have to figure out how to integrate with my legacy application (WebForms bleaghhh) after.